# time.NewTimer doesn't work as I expect

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have a fairly simple program, which is supposed to self-terminate after a specified duration of time (for example, one second)

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func emit(wordChannel chan string, done chan bool) {
    defer close(wordChannel)

    words := []string{"The", "quick", "brown", "fox"}
    i := 0
    t := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)

    for {
        select {
        case wordChannel <- words[i]:
            i++
            if i == len(words) {
                i = 0
            }
        // Please ignore the following case
        case <-done:
            done <- true
            // fmt.Printf("Got done!\n")
            close(done)
            return
        case <-t.C:
            fmt.Printf("\n\nGot done!\n\n")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    mainWordChannel := make(chan string)
    // Please ignore mainDoneChannel
    mainDoneChannel := make(chan bool)

    go emit(mainWordChannel, mainDoneChannel)

    for word := range mainWordChannel {
        fmt.Printf("%s  ", word)
    }

}
```

I compile and execute the binary, and you can see the execution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iCxT.jpg).

That is clearly above 1 second.

Go's documentation on [`NewTimer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTimer) reads this:

> **func NewTimer**
>
> `func NewTimer(d Duration) *Timer`
>
> NewTimer creates a new Timer that will send the current time on its channel after at least duration d.

Can someone kindly help me understand what's happening here? Why isn't the program terminating exactly (or closely `at least`) after 1 second?

Comment: Honestly it just looks to me like it probably only runs for a second but we're stuck watching the very slow terminal scroll. Comment out your printing and see how long it runs.

Comment: Tested it out on my machine. It is working working properly. You're mostly just dealing with slow terminal printing.

Comment: @Thomas That probably is...

Answer (score 4):

Timer works as intended. It sends a value to a channel.
I think it is useful to read [about select statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
Each iteration in your loop can write to a channel. 
If > 1 communication can proceed there is no guarantee which are.
So, if add delay to read loop like this :

```
for word := range mainWordChannel {
    fmt.Printf("%s  ", word)
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
}
```

In this case, only read from `timer.C` can proceed. And program will end.

Comment: Awesome. That does appear to work. But, honestly, I still don't understand why it worked? Do you care to elaborate a little further? That would be really helpful...

Comment: This isn't really a proper fix. I think you're just slowing down his printing enough that the terminal doesn't get excessively buffered.

Comment: I just want to reiterate that sleeping is pretty much never the answer! While your statement about select is true putting a sleep in here just makes his program run way slower. There is no actual problem with his program as it stands.

Comment: It isn't fixed. It illustrates the problem. Select statements have no guarantee which will proceed if several can. In your code value always can be written into `wordChannel`. And select do it. It never read from timer.C because it always can write to `wordChannel`.